ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (fisher)
I am trying to install fisher in Python using
pip install fisher

but I keep getting the following error:
Collecting fisher
        Using cached fisher-0.1.14.tar.gz (22 kB)
        Installing build dependencies ... done
        Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
      Collecting numpy (from fisher)
        Using cached numpy-2.1.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
      Using cached numpy-2.1.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.0 MB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: fisher
        Building wheel for fisher (pyproject.toml) ... error
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
        × Building wheel for fisher (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [118 lines of output]
      Failed to load config from /tmp/pip-install-ua4538cx/fisher_bd412cd798b24072b0c2e2088ab0a6cb/pyproject.toml: 'tool'
      Try to load it from setup.cfg
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Failed to load config from /tmp/pip-install-ua4538cx/fisher_bd412cd798b24072b0c2e2088ab0a6cb/pyproject.toml: 'tool'
      Try to load it from setup.cfg
      Failed to load config from /tmp/pip-install-ua4538cx/fisher_bd412cd798b24072b0c2e2088ab0a6cb/pyproject.toml: 'tool'
      Try to load it from setup.cfg
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/fisher
      copying fisher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/fisher
      copying fisher/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/fisher
      copying fisher/tableprinter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/fisher
      running egg_info
      writing fisher.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to fisher.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to fisher.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to fisher.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'fisher.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'README.rst'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'fisher.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      Failed to load config from /tmp/pip-install-ua4538cx/fisher_bd412cd798b24072b0c2e2088ab0a6cb/pyproject.toml: 'tool'
      Try to load it from setup.cfg
      UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/fisher/_version.py
      set build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/fisher/_version.py to '0.1.14'
      running build_ext
      /tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /tmp/pip-install-ua4538cx/fisher_bd412cd798b24072b0c2e2088ab0a6cb/src/cfisher.pyx
        tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          return pvalue(k, n - k, K - k, N - K - n + k)
      
      
      @cython.boundscheck(False)
      def pvalue_npy(
             np.ndarray[np.uint_t] a_true,
                           ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      src/cfisher.pyx:129:21: Invalid type.
      Failed to load config from /tmp/pip-install-ua4538cx/fisher_bd412cd798b24072b0c2e2088ab0a6cb/pyproject.toml: 'tool'
      Try to load it from setup.cfg
      Failed to load config from /tmp/pip-install-ua4538cx/fisher_bd412cd798b24072b0c2e2088ab0a6cb/pyproject.toml: 'tool'
      Try to load it from setup.cfg
      Compiling src/cfisher.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/cfisher.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/work/home/Software/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/work/home/Software/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/work/home/Software/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 421, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 403, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 67, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 117, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 954, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_wheel.py", line 384, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 1974, in run
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 98, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 359, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 476, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 502, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 263, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 130, in build_extension
          new_ext = cythonize(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-byd4dvj_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: src/cfisher.pyx
      [end of output]
  
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for fisher
      Failed to build fisher
      ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (fisher)

I have the following versions:
Python 3.12.3 and conda 24.7.1
Thanks for your help!

This is due to an incompatibility with numpy >=2.0, see also this github issue.
Try installing a compatible numpy version:
pip install "numpy<2.0"

